# How to test vibration function in android?

Tags: android, testing, cordova, vibration

I am writing a simple Phonegap application for Android. This program will send notification to notification bar and make the phone vibrate periodically.

I use `navigator.notification.vibrate(time_period)` to achieve the target. According to this [article](http://www.digitalnoiz.com/mobile-development/notifications-buttons/), both beep and vibration are not supported by android emulator. Hence, I was expecting that there could be entry indicating failure of it in the Catlog, but there is no such entry. The question is how to make sure that a vibration event has happened or failed (without deploying to a device).

[AppHarbor](http://www.justinsaraceno.com/2012/07/creating-with-phonegap-build-part-4/) looks like one of the ways to debug Phonegap application remotely. I wonder if there is other local ways to test Phonegap application as an HTML5 website in a Chrome browser (`navigator.notification` call is a standard call)? If yes, then it is probably possible to somehow parse the browser's console automatically to find out if the vibration event has happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you hide the vibrate() call behind an abstraction which you can replace depending on which platform you are using?

For example

```
var vibrateFunc = function(time_period) {
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
        console.log('vibrating for ' + time_period)
    } else {
        navigator.notification.vibrate(time_period)
    }
}
```

and then have your app code call vibrateFunc() whenever it wants to vibrate.